# Await, chained promises and flow control in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I would like to execute functions one after each other, using the value returned by the previous call into the next one.

I have it working using the following code :

```
var i = 0;

async function testn() {
  console.log('%s -> test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i+1, i++);
  setTimeout(console.log, timeout1, ' value of i in test%s : ', i, i);
  console.log('%s <- test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i, i);
  return {result: 0};
}

async function wrapIt() {
  await testn()
    .then(await testn())
    .then(await testn())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('caught %s', error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('finally %s', i);
    })
}

wrapIt();
```

And here is the output :

```
2021-07-14T12:23:56.677Z -> test1 (i = 0)
2021-07-14T12:23:56.678Z <- test1 (i = 1)
2021-07-14T12:23:56.678Z -> test2 (i = 1)
2021-07-14T12:23:56.678Z <- test2 (i = 2)
2021-07-14T12:23:56.678Z -> test3 (i = 2)
2021-07-14T12:23:56.678Z <- test3 (i = 3)
finally 3
 value of i in test1 :  1
 value of i in test2 :  2
 value of i in test3 :  3
```

If I use explicit Promises instead of the **async** keyword that implicitely returns a Promise, the behaviour changes (look at the delay between two calls of testn()).

```
var i = 0;
var timeout1 = 5000;
var timeout2 = 1000;

async function testn() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    console.log('%s -> test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i+1, i++);
    setTimeout(console.log, timeout1, ' value of i in test%s : ', i, i);
    console.log('%s <- test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i, i);
    setTimeout(() => {resolve({result: 0})}, timeout2);
  })
}

async function wrapIt() {
  await testn()
    .then(await testn())
    .then(await testn())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('caught %s', error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('finally %s', i);
    })
}
```

And here is the output :

```
2021-07-14T12:20:27.670Z -> test1 (i = 0)
2021-07-14T12:20:27.671Z <- test1 (i = 1)
2021-07-14T12:20:27.671Z -> test2 (i = 1)
2021-07-14T12:20:27.671Z <- test2 (i = 2)
2021-07-14T12:20:28.672Z -> test3 (i = 2)
2021-07-14T12:20:28.672Z <- test3 (i = 3)
finally 3
 value of i in test1 :  1
 value of i in test2 :  2
 value of i in test3 :  3
```

Why is the delay of 1 s. effective only between the 2nd and 3rd calls and not between the 1st and 2nd ones ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem shows up with Nodejs 14 and 16, although the latter introduces promises for the timers module.

Based on the finding that it is always the first call to setTimeout() that seems not to work, I solved the problem by adding a first 'fake' call to setTimeout().

```
var i = 0;
var timeout1 = 5000;
var timeout2 = 1000;

async function testn() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    console.log('%s -> test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i+1, i++);
    console.log(' value of i in test%s : ', i, i);
    console.log(' value of timeout1 in test%s : ', i, timeout1);
    console.log(' value of timeout2 in test%s : ', i, timeout2);
    console.log('%s <- test%s (i = %s)', new Date(), i, i);
    setTimeout(() => {resolve({result: 0})}, timeout2);
  })
}

async function wrapIt() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1))
    .then(await testn())
    .then(await testn())
    .then(await testn())
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('caught %s', error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('finally %s', i);
    })
}

wrapIt();
```

And here is the output :

```
2021-07-15T06:21:20.432Z -> test1 (i = 0)
 value of i in test1 :  1
 value of timeout1 in test1 :  5000
 value of timeout2 in test1 :  1000
2021-07-15T06:21:20.433Z <- test1 (i = 1)
2021-07-15T06:21:21.434Z -> test2 (i = 1)
 value of i in test2 :  2
 value of timeout1 in test2 :  5000
 value of timeout2 in test2 :  1000
2021-07-15T06:21:21.435Z <- test2 (i = 2)
2021-07-15T06:21:22.436Z -> test3 (i = 2)
 value of i in test3 :  3
 value of timeout1 in test3 :  5000
 value of timeout2 in test3 :  1000
2021-07-15T06:21:22.436Z <- test3 (i = 3)
finally 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is not related to `setTimeout`, you can use the value of `await` like a sync function call in the following way:

```js
async function testn(arg) {
      console.log(arg++);
      return arg;
}
 
async function wrapIt() {
   const res1 = await testn(0);
   const res2 = await testn(res1);
   const res3 = await testn(res2);
   console.log('finally %s', res3);     
}

wrapIt();
```

Comment: The question is indeed about setTimeout.  As async programming is fairly new to me (I started programming in the 80's), I am training myself and need to understand why the behaviour of setTimeout differs from one call to the other.